# How to match exact case in database for username in django model?

Tags: python, mysql, django, database, model

I working on django project. Actually I am learning. I have created custom user model. I am trying to match exact username case to let user login. My models.py file looks like,

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser


class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    uname = models.CharField(max_length=25, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    lname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    act_code = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    suspended = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'uname'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.uname
```

Here is my query to check user for login,

```
try:
   dbUserDetails = User.objects.raw("SELECT * FROM `hcAccounts_user` WHERE BINARY `uname` = '%s'",
                                                     cleaned_info['uname'])

except User.DoesNotExist:
       response_data = {'error': 'true', 'message': 'Wrong username!!!'}
```

So in my database I have tow users,

```
'abc' and 'Abcd'
```

This row query is giving me error

```
AttributeError at /accounts/login
'RawQuerySet' object has no attribute 'is_active'
```

This query,

```
dbUserDetails = User.objects.get(uname__iexact=cleaned_info['uname'])
```

is not matching case and if I use this query to login with user name 'abc',

```
dbUserDetails = User.objects.get(uname__contains=cleaned_info['uname'])
```

This will get both user as both uname contains 'abc'. It is not matching case. So can anyone tell me how can I match case for username to get information from database?

I tried a lot. I have searched a lot online for answer. I don't know what I have missed but I am stuck here.

Thank you for your time. I appreciate it.

Comment: `dbUserDetails = User.objects.get(uname__iexact=cleaned_info['uname'])` seems OK (if you are ok with case insensitive match). Have you tried looking at `cleaned_info['uname']` in the debugger or logging it?

Comment: `cleaned_info = loginForm.cleaned_data` and `loginForm = UserLoginForm(request.POST)`

Comment: Usernames should be case-insensitive

Comment: But to login, it should be. If some one has username like, `ExamPle`, user can login with anything like `exaMPLE` or `ExAmPlE` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, I know it is kinda dirty solution but it will work. ;)

```
if loginForm.is_valid():

    cleaned_info = loginForm.cleaned_data
    c = {}
    uid = ''

    err = ''
    try:
        c = User.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE BINARY `uname` = %s',
                                        cleaned_info['uname'])
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        err = 'UDNE'

        try:
            uid = c[0].id
        except IndexError:
            err = 'IE'

        if err is '':

            try:
                dbUserDetails = User.objects.get(uname__exact=cleaned_info['uname'],
                                                             id__exact=uid)

                 # Now you know that your username matches with "CASE"

                 # This is kinda dirty solution but will work so                  
                 # your logic codes will be here for login




            except User.DoesNotExist:
                response_data = {'error': 'true', 'message': 'Wrong username!!!'}

            else:
                response_data = {'error': 'true', 'message': 'Wrong username!!!'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error because `dbUserDetails` is a `RawQuerySet`, not a `User`. You need to iterate over `dbUserDetails` to get the user objects.

Anyway, the default behavior in Django is to be case sensitive, so the following should work:

```
dbUserDetails = User.objects.get(uname=cleaned_info['uname'])
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#field-lookups

Edit: Pay close attention to the note about MySQL (if that's what you're using):

> In MySQL, a database table’s “collation” setting determines whether exact comparisons are case-sensitive. This is a database setting, not a Django setting.

Comment: But it is not matching case. As I said, I have two users 'abc' and 'Abcd' so if I try to login with 'AbC', it will still get the first user. I want to match case for user name. Like `BINARY` in mysql

Comment: See my edit. In MySQL case sensitivity is determined by the collation, not Django. This should be helpful https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-sensitivity.html

Comment: just to confirm, are you checking the database default collation, or the table collation?

Comment: `uname` field collation is `utf8_bin`